# Display occurrence of number based off user input... array, java

Tags: java

I am trying to have a user enter in any amount of numbers they like then based upon their input use an array to count each occurrence of the numbers entered by the user. I know where i have my occurrence counter per say i am missing my return statement as that was one of the things i am  confused on, basically i am kind of stumped, yes this is homework and i do want to learn so i do not expect the full answer, just some input , thanks

package chapter_6;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author jason
 */
public class Six_Three {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = createArray();

    // prompt user for numbers
    System.out.println("Enter integers between 1 and 100: ");
    int data = input.nextInt();








}   
    // create array based off user input
    public static int[] createArray() {
        int[] num = new int[data];
        return num;
    }


    // count each occurence of input numbers from user   
    public static int[] countNumbers(int[] data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            return ?
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
Map<Integer,Integer>occur = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


for(int i=0; i< data.length;++i){
int num = data[i];

if(occur.containsKey(num) ){
int old_counter = occur.get(num);
map.put(num,old_counter++);
}
else
map.put(num,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems. First of all, you cannot access the variable `data` in any method except main, since that was where it was created. Secondly, your current code is only asking the user for one number, you'll need a loop to ask for multiple numbers. Here's some psuedocode.

```
Create an array with 100 spots and initialize them all to 0
Ask the user how many numbers they want to enter
Create a for loop that runs until the user has entered the amount of numbers specified
    Read in a number and store it in a variable (we'll call it n). 
    Add 1 to the (n-1)th spot in the array (For example, if the number entered was 7, set myarray[6] = myarray[6] + 1 )
Create a for loop that loops from 1-100
    Print out how many of each number was found
```

Comment: Thank you for the input and help, still a little confused but i will get it